# IntelliJ IDEA old model format

Tags: intellij-idea

Today I've updated IntelliJ IDEA EAP and got the following warning when opened a project:

> Project Data Sources
>   Model format version 2.2 is too old (2.3 or more required)

Though the project seems to be working fine. I have never seen this message before and I am concerned about this.

What does it mean? Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your project's DB settings and choose 'update driver' in the bottom of pop-up. At least that's how I resolved the issue.

Comment: You mean Database -> Data Source Properties ? I can't find 'update driver' option there. But dropping and creating connection again solved the problem.

Comment: Yep, that exactly what I meant